# Why? Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires that 'R' conform to 'RangeExpression'

Tags: swift

Why do In get here this error: `let subValue = subDict[key]`

> Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires that 'R' conform to 'RangeExpression'

```swift
import Foundation

func appendValue(_ toObject: inout Any, value: Any, keyPath: [Any]) {
    guard let key = keyPath.first else {
        return
    }
    if keyPath.count > 1 {
        if let subDict = toObject as? [String: Any], let subValue = subDict[key] { // <----
            var newSubDict = subDict
            appendValue(&newSubDict[key as! String]!, value: value, keyPath: Array(keyPath.dropFirst()))
            toObject = newSubDict
        } else if let subArray = toObject as? [Any], let index = key as? Int, subArray.indices.contains(index) {
            var newSubArray = subArray
            appendValue(&newSubArray[index], value: value, keyPath: Array(keyPath.dropFirst()))
            toObject = newSubArray
        }
    } else {
        if var subDict = toObject as? [String: Any] {
            subDict[key as! String] = value
            toObject = subDict
        } else if var subArray = toObject as? [Any], let index = key as? Int, subArray.indices.contains(index) {
            subArray[index] = value
            toObject = subArray
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `subDict` is a `[String:Any]`, so in `subDict[key]`,  `key` has to be a `String`, but `key` is `Any`.. I think that the error message is misleading though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because key requires a string value..

```
let subValue = subDict[key as? String ?? ""]
```

please convert the key variable into string.